# Disable Circuit Breaker (Hystrix) in Zuul for specific spring profiles?

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul, hystrix

We have several negative test cases that we run as part of our integration suite. These cases have a nasty habit of apparently tripping the `hystrix` circuit breaker and disabling servers that are delivering expected bad responses.

I'd like to configure the spring profile in `Zuul` to disable the circuit breaker in our test environment.

I had attempted to use

```
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.enabled: false
```

It looks like it may work if I define this for each possible hystrix command key (which I haven't dug into how to find yet). Assuming this would be the correct configuration, is there a way to wildcard it, or otherwise just turn off hystrix for certain spring profiles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Zuul` but you can use Hystrix `ConfigurationManager` for tuning your parameters.

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance()
                    .setProperty("hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.enabled", false);
```